# Stop incremental counter and disable interaction

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to get the counter to stop at 0 and when it does the entire div is unclickable/disable interaction.
There is a link in the middle. So when i click 3 times I want it to be un-clickable.

edit:also it doesn't need to use Knockout. any approach, if more simple is fine.

What would be the best approach?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5egxfa94/)

```
 var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
     this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(3);

     this.registerClick = function() {
         this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() - 1);
     };

     this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.numberOfClicks() <= 0;
     }, this);
    };

 ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

Comment: `disable` doesn't apply to `div`s or even to links. You'll have to handle that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try adding this line

```
if (this.numberOfClicks() > 0)
```

Before

```
this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() - 1);
```

We'll get something like that:

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(3);

    this.registerClick = function() {
        if (this.numberOfClicks() > 0)
            this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() - 1);
    };

    this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.numberOfClicks() <= 0;
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5egxfa94/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but give a look to my solution because I simplified a lot your code and I think you can get some value from it (for example the use of `var self = this` which is a best practice).

The idea behind my solution is very simple:

1) Show or hide the link or a normal text with respect to your hasClickedTooManyTimes computed variable.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="ifnot: hasClickedTooManyTimes">empty link</a>
<p data-bind='if: hasClickedTooManyTimes'>empty link</p>
```

2) Simply block the click on div if hasClickedTooManyTimes is true.

```
self.registerClick = function() {
    if(!self.hasClickedTooManyTimes()){
        self.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() - 1);
    }
};
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9p8b65p/1/)!

Let me know if this was useful to you!

Answer (score -1):

Just disable the link when your count is done:

First add an `id` to your link:

```
<a id="a1" href=#> <p>empty link</p> </a>
```

Next disable that id when the time is right like this in your javascript:

```
this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.numberOfClicks() < 0) {
        $('#a1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   // <--- disable it
    }
    return this.numberOfClicks() <= 0;
}, this);
```

Comment: This is bad advice. Don't manipulate the DOM from your view models with an MVVM framework like KnockoutJS. Manipulate your view models, and declaratively have Knockout update the DOM through bindings.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the fiddle for JS code, stackoverflow is not validating my code section for the JS content.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>You have <a href="#" id="mybtn">teste</a> clicks!</div>
    <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var btnObserver = (function() {
    var me= this;
    var clickleft = 3;

    var registerClick = function() {
        if(clickleft > 0) {
            clickleft--;
        }
    };

    var isCLickable = function() {
        console.log(clickleft);
        return clickleft !== 0;
    };

    return {
        registerClick: registerClick,
        isCLickable: isCLickable
    }    
})();

    document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var message= "Hello World";
        btnObserver.registerClick();

        if(!btnObserver.isCLickable()) {
            message= "X  Blocked!";
            // return false or do anything you need here
        } 

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message;
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qkafjmdp/